# Change tikz plot style parameters (numbers on axes, size of points) to match previous ones

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs, tikz-graphs

I want to modify a graph to be in agreement with the previous ones in my paper. Throughout my document I have plotted with the following style:

[image]
[image]

the codes are as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[H] %Parabola
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = \(t\),
        ylabel = {\(f(t)\)},
        ]
        \addplot [
        domain=0:1, 
        samples=100, 
        color=black,
        line width=1pt,
        ]
        {4*(x- 1/2)^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H] %Discrete
\centering
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        every axis x label={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
        every axis y label={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor= north west},
        every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=black}},
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={},
        xtick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=7.0,
        ]
        \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {original.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}\end{figure}
```

I'm using:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.3}
```

**Note in particular the thickness of the lines, the size of the points on the discrete graph and the numbering on both axes.** Now, I recently found a useful way to graph piecewise functions and I get the following:

[image]

with this code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\piecewise}[1]{
    \foreach \f/\a/\b/\open/\closed in {#1}{%
        \draw[domain=\a:\b, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, \f);
        \foreach \x[evaluate={\y=\f;}] in \open{%
            \draw[fill=white] (\x,\y) circle (.8mm);
        }
        \foreach \x[evaluate={\y=\f;}] in \closed{%
            \draw[fill] (\x,\y) circle (.8mm);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[->] (-2, 0) -- (7, 0) node[right] {$x$};
            \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 3) node[above] {$f(x)$};
            \begin{scope}[line width=0.5pt]
                \piecewise{{-\x+1}/-2/-1/{}/{-2,-1}, 
                    {\x/3 + 7/3}/-1/2/{}/{2},
                    {-\x + 5}/2/4/{}/{4},
                    {-\x + 6}/4/6/{4}/{6}}
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

**I want to get the exact size of the endpoints with that of the discrete plot; also the line thickness and numbering on the axes**, this in order to be consistent in my document; I don't know how to do it though. I would appreciate your help a lot.

This is the complete code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.3}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents}{original.dat}
    n   xn 
    1   6.0  
    2   1.0  
    3   3.0  
    4   1.0 
    5   7.0
    6   4.0
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\piecewise}[1]{
    \foreach \f/\a/\b/\open/\closed in {#1}{%
        \draw[domain=\a:\b, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, \f);
        \foreach \x[evaluate={\y=\f;}] in \open{%
            \draw[fill=white] (\x,\y) circle (.8mm);
        }
        \foreach \x[evaluate={\y=\f;}] in \closed{%
            \draw[fill] (\x,\y) circle (.8mm);
        }
    }
}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = left,
            xlabel = \(t\),
            ylabel = {\(f(t)\)},
            ]
            \addplot [
            domain=0:1, 
            samples=100, 
            color=black,
            line width=1pt,
            ]
            {4*(x- 1/2)^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
    

    
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            every axis x label={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
            every axis y label={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor= north west},
            every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=black}},
            xlabel={$n$},
            ylabel={},
            xtick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=7.0,
            ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {original.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
    
    
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[->] (-2, 0) -- (7, 0) node[right] {$x$};
            \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 3) node[above] {$f(x)$};
            \begin{scope}[line width=0.5pt]
                \piecewise{{-\x+1}/-2/-1/{}/{-2,-1}, 
                    {\x/3 + 7/3}/-1/2/{}/{2},
                    {-\x + 5}/2/4/{}/{4},
                    {-\x + 6}/4/6/{4}/{6}}
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as understood your question, you like to have `tikz` picture (drawn by command `\piecewise` the same image size. the same mark size and the same line thickness. This can be relative simple to achieve, if you will drawn all images as `pgfplots` images. If this is not acceptable option for you, than you need to do the following:

- scale image so, that you will get the same width of of image

  In your case `pgfplots` diagrams widths are (in MWE below) 6cm, x-axis in `tikzpicure` has length 9 units.  That both diagrams will have the same width, ˙its units should be `6cm/9`
- line thickness should be the same as is in `pgfplots` (`very thick` in MWE below)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,
             width=6cm, height=4.5cm,
             scale only axis,
             }
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1},
         every mark/.append style={scale=1.5},
         }

\begin{filecontents}{original.dat}
    n   xn
    1   6.0
    2   1.0
    3   3.0
    4   1.0
    5   7.0
    6   4.0
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\piecewise}[1]{
    \foreach \f/\a/\b/\open/\closed in {#1}{%
        \draw[domain=\a:\b, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, \f);
        \foreach \x[evaluate={\y=\f;}] in \open{%
            \draw[fill=white] (\x,\y) circle (.8mm);
        }
        \foreach \x[evaluate={\y=\f;}] in \closed{%
            \draw[fill] (\x,\y) circle (.8mm);
        }
    }
}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = left,
            xlabel = \(t\),
            ylabel = \(f(t)\),
            ]
    \addplot [domain=0:1,
              samples=100,
              very thick,
             ]  {4*(x- 1/2)^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel={$n$},
            xtick=data,
            ymin=0, ]
            \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {original.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=6cm/9]
        \draw[->] (-2, 0) -- (7, 0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 3) node[above] {$f(x)$};
        \begin{scope}[very thick]
            \piecewise{{-\x+1}/-2/-1/{}/{-2,-1},
                {\x/3 + 7/3}/-1/2/{}/{2},
                {-\x + 5}/2/4/{}/{4},
                {-\x + 6}/4/6/{4}/{6}}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

drawn
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,     xlabel style={anchor=west},
            ylabel=$f(x)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            xmax=7,
            ymin=-0.3
                    ]
       \addplot [very thick,red,mark=*]
            coordinates { (-2,3) (-1,2) (2,3) (4,1) };
       \addplot [very thick,red,o-*, shorten <>=-2\pgflinewidth]
            coordinates {(4,2) (6,0) };
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Off-topic:**

- In preamble each package load only ones
- I slightly modified axis preamble (to be more consistent and short)
- I define size of diagrams (without labels). On this way is simpler to scale used units in `tikz` images (otherwise you need to guess scale factor)
- last image (with red curves) is for comparison drawn as `pgfplots` diagram.  In it I manually calculate coordinates what not seems to be a big drawback in compare with your `\piecewise` function.

**Addendum:**
Modification of the last image as OP required in his coment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,
             width=6cm, height=4.5cm,
             scale only axis,
             }
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1},
         every mark/.append style={scale=1.5}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            grid,                  % <--- added 
            grid style = {dashed}, % <--- added
            xlabel=$x$,     xlabel style={anchor=west},
            ylabel=$f(x)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
            xmin=-3,    xmax=7,  % <--- changed
            ymin=-0.5,  ymax=3.5 % <--- changed
                    ]
       \addplot [very thick,mark=*]
            coordinates { (-2,3) (-1,2) (2,3) (4,1) };
       \addplot [very thick,o-*, shorten <>=-2.5\pgflinewidth]
            coordinates {(4,2) (6,0) };
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

or 

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            grid,                    % <--- added
            grid style = {dashed},   % <--- added
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$f(x)$,
                    ]
       \addplot [very thick,mark=*]
            coordinates { (-2,3) (-1,2) (2,3) (4,1) };
       \addplot [very thick,o-*, shorten <>=-2.5\pgflinewidth]
            coordinates {(4,2) (6,0) };
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand the pgfplots part and will use that. In the red plot how can I place the grid (or numbering) on the axes?

Comment: @nkeLeAdo, just remove `xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty`, add `grid` option. See addendum to answer (will appear ASAP)

Comment: @nkeLeAdo, done. Lines are now black, but you can change color as you wish (see firs example.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @nkeLeAdo, you are welcome. BTW, you may consider to upvote my answer or even accept it (by clicking on up-triangle and checkmark, which are at top left side of answer) :-). As I see, so far you not accept any of received answers ...